# How to run a delayed or scheduled task in Java provided you have a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

Suppose I have a thread from a thread pool. How to execute delated/scheduled task (Runnable or Callable) in this thread?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a Thread directly for that.

Use, for instance, a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

The [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class is probably what you want to create one.

Comment: What confused me is the fact that the OP wants to *execute runnables* in a `Thread` . He can't do it

Comment: @TheLostMind well, there _is_ a constructor for `Thread` which takes a `Runnable` as an argument, no? Bah

Comment: Right. Infact a thread itself is also a *Runnable* :P.. Although I think you are right.. A `ScheduledExceutorService` will fit the OPs needs